# How to get current Process StartTime in UTC

Tags: .net

My tests show that `Process.GetCurrentProcess().StartTime` returns a local time.

Obviously I can convert this to UTC using `ToUniversalTime()`, but this can give the wrong time if the process started at an ambiguous local time when the clock goes backwards at the end of DST.

Is there a straightforward way of getting the start time in UTC?

Comment: Not an answer, but here is a relevant TimeZone Rant video. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-5wpm-gesOY  Hopefully, you can laugh a bit while waiting on your answer.